# Hold a function call until click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I'm in a bit tricky situation because I have a function generating an array which I'd like to pass to another function after a button's been clicked. To crystallize it for you, I'm talking about sth like this:

```
function d(){
...
while(true){
  m.push([x,y]);
  ...//we have finished pushing things into the array
}
  if(false){
  //here I have to somehow pause the function and make it wait until 
  $('#idofabutton').data('clicked');
  //and after this step has been passed, to call another function passing it   the generated array...
function mo(m);
 }
}
```

That's it, if you have any suggestions, please comment I'm open to any ideas but I'd prefer to stick to this structure of the program without shuffling it or rewriting it because it was difficult enough for me to bring it to where it is... :)
P.S. Just to add, beside from this I've also said:

```
  $('idofabutton').click(function(){
     $(this).data('clicked', true);
  });
```

P.S.2 If it's possible consider passing mo() to the jquery function, if this is possible I'll with ease re-transfer it to the targeted one, it would be even better, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a click handler with a callback function that references the array you created:

```js
// display the contents of the array m
function mo(m) {
  $("#arraycontents").html(JSON.stringify(m));
}

function d() {
  var m = [];

  // build the array
  while (m.length < 10) {
    m.push([m.length, m.length * 2]);
  }

  // register the click callback
  $('#idofabutton').click(function(e) {
    mo(m);
  });
}

// call the function d() to build the array and register the click handler
d();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="idofabutton">Click Me!</button>
<div id="arraycontents"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i'm sure there are many way to do this but here is one way.

```
var stillRun = true;

function execute(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(stillRun)
            {
            $("#someId").append("t")
            execute();
            }
        },10)
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#someButton").click(function(){
        alert("stop")
        stillRun = false;
    })
    execute();
})
```

Basically the `setTimeout` makes it so the on click will actually be reachable and  also the page wont crash from a infinite loop.

Here is the [JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bv69exLj/)